# Manage files on iDevices

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, file-management

Does anyone know how programs like iPhoneExplorer manage to list/add/remove files on an iDevice?

I would like to do something similar (but more basic) in a Cocoa Touch application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically not an Apple-approved™ method, so don't plan on putting this in the App Store. But it is possible. First, import the MobileDevice framework from `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`. Then use the reverse-engineered header for the MobileDevice framework:

http://code.google.com/p/ziphone/source/browse/trunk/ZiPhone/MobileDevice.h

It includes all the methods necessary to communicate with an attached iOS device.

There's also a C++ wrapper for it that's a bit easier to use, especially for detecting the device in the first place. It also includes methods specifically for jailbreaking, but they're not required.

http://code.google.com/p/independence/source/browse/trunk/libPhoneInteraction/PhoneInteraction.cpp?r=323

Comment: It's a pity it will not approved on the appstore. Thanks for your answer.